# How to install a specific kernel version (4.15.0)?

Tags: kernel

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm running this kernel version:

```
root@sintrones-vbox:/usr/src# uname -r
5.4.0-122-generic
```

In the folder `usr/src`, I have:

```
root@sintrones-vbox:/usr/src# ls
backport-iwlwifi-8324             linux-headers-4.15.0-189          linux-hwe-5.4-5.4.0                          linux-hwe-5.4_5.4.0.orig.tar.gz  linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
linux-headers-4.15.0-162          linux-headers-4.15.0-189-generic  linux-hwe-5.4_5.4.0-122.138~18.04.1.diff.gz  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-122
linux-headers-4.15.0-162-generic  linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic   linux-hwe-5.4_5.4.0-122.138~18.04.1.dsc      linux-source-4.15.0
```

Is there a way to install the kernel version `4.15.0`? It was the previous kernel version before I upgraded it.
I've several kernels installed:

```
root@sintrones-abox:/usr/src# apt list --installed | grep linux-image

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-image-4.15.0-162-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0-162.170 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-4.15.0-189-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0-189.200 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.4.0-122-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.4.0-122.138~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-extra-virtual/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0.189.174 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0.189.174 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.18.14-051814-generic/now 5.18.14-051814.202207231131 amd64 [installed,local]
```

The problem is that I want to switch to the 4.15 version

---

I've several kernels installed:

```
root@sintrones-abox:/usr/src# apt list --installed | grep linux-image

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-image-4.15.0-162-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0-162.170 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-4.15.0-189-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0-189.200 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.4.0-122-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.4.0-122.138~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-extra-virtual/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0.189.174 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0.189.174 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-unsigned-5.18.14-051814-generic/now 5.18.14-051814.202207231131 amd64 [installed,local]
```

The problem is that I want to switch to the 4.15 version

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? `linux-source-4.15.0` is not a valid ubuntu kernel, it is a source package. Please [edit] the question and explain what is the real problem.

Comment: I would need to install the 4.15 kernel

Comment: You already have the 4.15 kernel installed if you didn't install only headers. `4.15.0-xxx` are the 4.15.

Comment: just choose the other kernel in GRUB when you boot

Comment: Reboot and you should boot into the 4.15 kernel.

Comment: Are you sure you have Ubuntu 18.04? It is more likely you have the 20.04 release.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS the GA kernel stack is 4.15; with 5.4 being the HWE stack (at 18.04.5 and later including current 18.04.6).  Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  You can have both GA & HWE stacks installed (*though some closed-source 3rd party kernel modules such as video drivers/modules can prevent both stacks co-existing, but if using all open source you'll not have issues*)

Comment: This question is confusing. Your own output clearly shows that you already have kernel 4.15.0 installed, so it's unclear why you are asking to install it. Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify exactly what problem you are encountering that has led you to believe installing that kernel is the best solution?

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is uninstall the HWE kernel and fall back to the GA kernel. I believe the GA kernel is in the package named "linux-generic". While I'm not 100% sure on this, I think you can just uninstall all the kernels that are above the 4.15 kernel you want, then install the "linux-generic" package, and that should continue to give you security updates on that kernel. One last thing - if you're trying to stay on a lower kernel for the sake of VirtualBox Guest Additions, you may just need to upgrade VirtualBox.